# How to click on button inside Excel Sheet using selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have few excels to automate which includes click on element inside excel, then save the excel to particular path, and enter user name and password to excel.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.

Selenium is a tool used to drive a web browser, not a tool to interact with Excel.

You could use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org) to programatically manipulate Excel files.

Comment: I used POI for excel interactions but i need to enter user name and password for excel to open  and then I have to click on button inside excel. How should I do this using POI?

Comment: Why do you need to physically click on a button in excel?Just manipulate the file with Apache POI and programatically save it wherever you want to.

Comment: As my project is retail domain, i have so many excel macros to automate. is there any solution to automate excel macros? that means i need to perform actions inside excel like click, select from dropdown, enter username and pwd and my company is not allowing to install AutoIT as it is having high vulnarability.

Comment: This doesn't sound at all related to selenium, you may want to remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate and use AutoIT with your selenium framework. 
Read about it.

But usually, UFT is preferred choice of tool for excel operations and running macros.

Comment: I am at the end stage of my project now I cannot change the tool, is it not possible with selenium ?

Comment: In such scenarios, we usually mark the test as Non Automatable. But you can still do it using AutoIT which is a library that integrates with Selenium Frameworks.